# How to add a text on mapView in swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, mkmapview

I'm trying to display a text at a certain location on a mapView.
I can display annotations, overlays like polylines, etc.

But how can I do to display a simple text directly on a map ?

I can't find any documentation on that anywhere (for the moment ;)

Thanks for your help !